# scheduled cron starting every day at 6pm and ending 22pm

Tags: java

Can someone help me building a @Scheduled cron
every 5 minutes, starting every day at 6am. and ending at 22pm
I tried this code, but I'm not sure.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/2 6-22 * * ?", zone = "America/Sao_Paulo")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 6-22 * * *", zone = "America/Sao_Paulo")
```

To see if it's working as expected do as:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 6-22 * * *", zone = "America/Sao_Paulo")
public void reportCurrentTime() {
     System.out.println("Testing " + new Date());
}
```

Comment: Seems like that won't stop at 22:00 but will continue until 22:55.

Comment: Yes, it will continue until 22:55, the moment that 22 ends and 23 starts. On the other hand, someone may prefer to stop it at 21:55. In this case, we need to change the cron expression to "0 0/5 6-21 * * *".

Comment: How can it be made to stop at 22:00?

Comment: I guess you will need to create a separate one for 22:00 ("0 0 22 * * *).